# Linq Distinct only in next rows match

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a datatable with the following information:

```
365.00
370.00
369.59
365.00
365.00 -> match with previous item
365.00 -> match with previous item
```

I only need to remove the next matched items, like this:

```
365.00
370.00
369.59
365.00
```

I tried:

```
(from articlespricehistory in dt.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
   articlepricehistory_cost = articlespricehistory.Field<Double>("articlepricehistory_cost")
})
.DistinctBy(i => i.articlepricehistory_cost)
.ToList();
```

Result:

```
365.00
370.00
369.59
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
    T previous = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    foreach(T item in items)
    {
        if (first || !Equals(previous, item)) 
        {
            first = false;
            previous = item;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, as requested, with a selector

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyDistinct<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, U> selector) 
{
    U previous = default(U);
    bool first = true;
    foreach(T item in items)
    {
        U current = selector(item);
        if (first || !Equals(previous, current)) 
        {
            first = false;
            previous = current;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your reason behind relying on foreach to maintain the order?

Comment: Hy Thank you for your answer, so you know how i can add an selector to this Expression? Like this: `.MyDistinct(i => i.articlepricehistory_cost)`  because i need only compare one column

Comment: @displayName: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify it?

Comment: @EricLippert: You are running a for-each over an IEnumerable. Are we guaranteed that a for-each loop will iterate over the price list in order?

Comment: @displayName: I still don't understand the question. The loop enumerates the enumerable in an order determined by the enumerable; that's what it *means* to be an enumerable. If you don't like that order then take it up with the provider of the enumerable object.

Comment: @EricLippert: A single comment by you packs so much! :-) I never really thought about LINQ that way. Your answer is correct. If you can answer, I'd like to know if multiple calls to dt.AsEnumerable will return the items in same order every time.

Comment: @EricLippert: Actually no need. I understood.

Comment: @displayName: In general, I recommend against enumerating over an `IEnumerable` more than once, as the enumerable's output is lazily evaluated each time.  A second hit to an enumerable can return different results, hit a database, throw an exception, or return no results.  That's not to say it's always unsafe, but it depends upon the underlying source of the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks... I understood that after ELippert's comment and thusly understood why his answer is correct. If the IEnumerable is not returning the same order every time, then OP is wrongly doing `from articlespricehistory in dt.AsEnumerable()` in his/her LINQ at the first place. So assuming that OP's IEnumerable is returning same order always, this is the best answer. Otw, I had the same fears. In my own answer I first materialized the enumeration using `.ToList()`.

Comment: @displayName: Glad to help. The way I often summarize Brian's point here is **a query expression represents a question, not an answer**. Enumerating the query actually asks the question; whether the answer to a question is the same every time you ask depends on what the question is and who you're asking.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks for the [perfect metaphor](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=steve+mcconnell+metaphors&source=bl&ots=RlJsLJtsOT&sig=Ma18DY4whhnFo5SnS8QfDs5jYys&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMIzv6X35m9yAIVjJINCh1c3gUv#v=onepage&q=steve%20mcconnell%20metaphors&f=false) about LINQs. C# is your mother tongue? :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a neat LINQ solution for u

```
var list = (dt as Enumerable);

var numbers = list.TakeWhile((currentItem, index) => currentItem != list.ElementAtOrDefault(index - 1));
```

Keep in mind if u have 0 as the first element it will be ommitted from the new list since ElementAtOrDefault will return 0 in the first iteration of the while loop (index of -1), thus evaluating the expression to false. A simple if statement can help you avoid this.

Comment: I note that if you have to introduce a note explaining the code, then the code is insufficiently clear. Why not simply say `TakeWhile((currentItem, index) => ...` and eliminate the note?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea I have not actually tried

- Do a `Skip(1)` on the query to produce a second query.
- Now append to the second query any element not equal to the last element in the first query, to produce a third query.
- Now zip join the first and third queries together to form a set of pairs; this is the fourth query.
- Now construct a fifth query that filters out pairs that have identical elements from the fourth query.
- Finally, construct a sixth query that selects the first element of each pair from the fifth query.

The sixth query is the data set you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query is that you are using `.DistinctBy()` which will return distinct results only. So if 365.00 appeared anywhere, it won't show up in the returned list again.

```
var differentPreviousList = new List<double>();
var itemPriceList = dt.ToList();
differentPreviousList.Add(itemPriceList[0]);
for (var index = 1; index < itemPriceList.Count; index++)
{
    if (itemPriceList[index - 1] == itemPriceList[index]) continue;
    differentPriceList.Add(itemPriceList[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a temporary value to check if the next value matches the current value or not.

```
double temporary = -1;  // temp value for checking
List<double> results = new List<double>(); // list to store results

(from articlespricehistory in dt.AsEnumerable()
 select new
 {
    articlepricehistory_cost = articlespricehistory.Field<Double>("articlepricehistory_cost")
 })
  .Select(a => a.articlepricehistory_cost)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(cost => 
  {
      if (temporary != cost) { results.Add(cost); }
      temporary = cost;
  });

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

After `ForEach` method is equivalent to the following.

```
foreach (var cost in costs)
{
    if (temporary != cost)
    {
        results.Add(cost);
        Console.WriteLine(cost);
    }
    temporary = cost;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a `ForEach` containing statements to modify a temporary variable, why not simply modify the `foreach` loop below it?

Comment: You're right. My code is equivalent to using foreach loop. I've added another version.
I used ForEach method just to avoid setting the first results to a new list and as usual for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an elegant solution but I would just parse a bare query..here is how.

1. Run a lambda query to get all the original results without trying to filter out DistinctBy.
2. Create an object of a single query result of the type you initially queried for.
3. Initialize a new list for foreach parse results.
4. Do a for each loop for each result.
5. The first if section should be if(object above loop is null).
6. IF is true add item to list
7. ELSE if check to see if value of item is same as the last iteration.
8. Store foreach iteration object to the object declared before the loop.

Rinse and repeat, and the result is no duplicate objects found in a row in the loop will be stored in the list resulting in what you wanted.